# Scraper banned from accesing google trends, regular browser still works

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

Quite a while ago I made a scraper in `python` with `Selenium` (chromedriver) to get some data from google trends. It works well but sometimes I get blocked and get error 429, too many requests. The ban can last up to several days (oof). The weird thing is that with my regular browser I can still make the same requests without problems, so I guess is not an IP ban. **How does google identify each browser? Why my regular browser doesn't get 429 error at the same time?** I'm not interested in the reason for the ban (obviously too many requests in a short a mount of time) but how each browser is treated independently. **Google trends knows is the same browser making requests, how?**

Comment: `Selenium` runs fresh browser without cookies - so if server uses cookies to accept user then Selenium needs more code to run with `profile`. Besides server may check also time between requests and use this to block you - and this is why some modules (like `scrapy`) uses random delay between requests. Real human can't load 100 pages in 1 second and and it can't delay 1ms between loaded pages. Human always need more time and this time is more random. `Selenium` use some JavaScript to control brower and some server can detect this JavaScript code and block `Selenium`.

Comment: Again, the scraper works well most of the time, only when I make too many requests I get error 429 (so no cookies). I can wait half an hour to do a new request, I'm still blocked with 429. What I want to know is why my regular chrome browser can access trends while the scraper is blocked. If they knew it was a scraper they could ban it outright. They don't, the scraper works most of the time.

Comment: but scraper works faster then real human and more regular then real human - and Google has big money to create complex system to recognize bots/scripts - it may use even Machime Learning, Neural Network for this.

Comment: not really, you can add a simple line of code like `time.sleep(30)` after each request and it doesn't, is trivial. The only thing is that there seems to be a hard cap for requests in trends. But that's not what I'm asking.

Comment: Google trends knows is the same browser, thats what I'm getting at. How does it know.

Comment: as I said Google may have very complex system to recognize bots/scripts - it doesn't have to check only what browser it uses but also other HTTP headers, plugins, JavaScript elements, etc. Selenium doesn't have to use the same settings. And it doesn't have to use the same cookies, the same plugins, the same ports.

Comment: Yes, you are probably right, but you are not answering my question.

Comment: by the way: there is such concept like `"browser fingerprint"` which uses many elements to recognize user - sometimes with probability 90%. Wikipedia: [Device fingerprint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_fingerprint) and Mozilla: [What is fingerprinting?](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/features/block-fingerprinting/)

Comment: I can't answer for your question because it is too complex - it may use so many elements to recognize browser which I don't even know.

Comment: Yes it probably has something to do with the browser fingerprint. I changed the user-agent and downloaded a new chromedriver but it still knows is the same. But thanks.